# How to set -n (number of users ) for database server?

Tags: openedge, progress-db

> We have increased the -n parameter in broker/db.pf file.We restarted the server and  when we check in promon its still showing the same number of users. How do we increase the -n parameter?

Comment: issue resolved.We didn't use the pf file to start the database.we simply started using proserve db-name and thatsy it didnt reflect in promon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you answered this yourselves but for future users a real answer can be good. There are several ways to set parameters like -n. This answer really applies to changing all startup parameters (but not what values are "good").

How you change this value depends on how you start your database. See below.

*NB 1: you should be aware of your licensing plan before changing this number and contact your sales contact if needed.*

*NB 2: you should be aware that changing startup parameters can affect performance etc. Test new values in a separate environment before moving them to production.*

*NB 3: backup all files before messing around...*

## Managed Database

A managed database is a database that is handled by the AdminServer. OE Management is not needed for this approach. A working installation of OE Explorer is however recommended.

The managed database is started (and stopped etc) via either the web based OE Explorer interface or the `dbman` command line utility.

Settings are stored in `conmgr.properties` under your Progress installation. You can edit this file manually (save a copy first...) or via the OE Explorer (recommended way).

You will have a line like this in the file:

```
 maxusers=20                     # -n
```

Edit the number to your liking with your favourite editor.

You can also change this in the OE Explorer:

1. Log in to OE Explorer. Default location is `http://servername:9090/`.
2. Locate and click on the database (if it's not there it's not handled by the adminserver - see below).
3. Select Configuration
4. Select Configuration (again, not "servergroup")
5. Click EDIT
6. -n (or Max users) is located in the first group of settings ("General"). See picture below.
7. Edit the value and don't forget to save.
   [image: OE Explorer changing configuration]

## Scripted Database

A scripted database is a database that started with a custom script (or also directly from command line). The actual startup could be handled by crontab, a user, the server generic startup script etc. 
The OE AdminServer is not "aware" of this database. (You can make the AdminServer "a little" aware of it by running the `dbagent` command line utility with certain parameters. Read more about this in the manual).

You could generally divide into two ways of handling the script: with parameters in it or with parameters in a separate parameter file (often with the extension .pf).

**Script with parameters in it**

With this approach you store all parameters in the actual startup script.

```
proserve <dbname> -H <hostname> -S <serviceport> -n 10 -B 10000 -spin 10000 etc..
```

**Script with a separate parameter file**

With this approach you store the parameters in a separate file.

```
proserve <dbname> -pf /path/to/file/file.pf
```

The .pf-file can be formatted like the parameters in the command line:

```
-db <dbname> -H <hostname> -S <service> etc.
```

Or with newlines (this allows for comments in the file):

```
# Main database
-db <dbname>
-H <hostname>
-S <service>
```

You can also mix these two approaches.

Sources:

[OE Management and OE Explorer](http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge114/pdfs/oemgs/oemgs.pdf)

[OE Database Management](http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge114/pdfs/dmadm/dmadm.pdf)